# Firebase return onAddChild

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to return every `dataSnapshot.getKey()` in `onAddchild` to the main method to be used and back to this method to add a new child again, here is my code

```
private String NameSub(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    RootRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            NameSub = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.i("ttttttttttttttttttttt20", NameSub);
            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    Log.i("ttttttttttttttttttttt21", String.valueOf(NameSub));
    return NameSub;
}
```

I'm logging to trace the code and it's giving me `Log"ttttttttttttttttttttt21"` beftore `Log"ttttttttttttttttttttt20"`. Also, giving me `null` value towards the `21 Logs`.

How is it that the code is working, but it is printing `Log 21` before `Log 20`? How can I fix that?

NB: I'm receiving no null value of dataSnapshot from another Firebase method

Comment: It's because `NameSub` is updated in callback.

Comment: will you explain more please

Comment: Why is NameSub both a variable as well as a function name?

Comment: changing them for 2 different name make no sense the compiler know how to Differentiates between them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new ChildEventListener() { ... }` is a callback.

When your function is called, this is what happens.

```
private String NameSub(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    RootRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { ... });
    Log.i("ttttttttttttttttttttt21", String.valueOf(NameSub));
    return NameSub;
}
```

So your function returns a `null` value.

Later whenever a child is added to your firebase realtime database, `onChildAdded(...)` is called.
This happens asynchronously. This updates the `NameSub` value.

So your code is printing `Log 21` before `Log 20`.

Comment: so at first the ChildEventListener is caller without anything?!!, NB: that those values are already added in the fire base but just loading them for the first time

Comment: Also how could I run the onChildAdded first to return the value

Comment: No. It is `ChildEventListener` is just another object. So in your function the callback will run concurrently with rest of your function code. So `Log20` is printed after `Log21`

Comment: You can't run `onChildAdded` first, because it is a callback and it will run asynchronously.

Comment: thank you, then I have to see another way to get the child of the child correctly